# Unfortunately Stopped RecyclerView in fragment with JSON

Tags: android, mysql, sql, json, android-recyclerview

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main 1
>
> 0-21 15:37:18.680 20525-20525/info.androidhive.loginandregistration
>   E/AndroidRuntime: Process: info.androidhive.loginandregistration, PID:
>   20525 10-21 15:37:18.680
>   20525-20525/info.androidhive.loginandregistration E/AndroidRuntime:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(boolean)' on a
>   null object reference 10-21 15:37:18.680
>   20525-20525/info.androidhive.loginandregistration E/AndroidRuntime:
>   at
>   info.androidhive.loginandregistration.activity.ByobovateFragment.onCreateView(ByobovateFragment.java:92)
>   10-21 15:37:18.680 20525-20525/info.androidhive.loginandregistration
>   E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1965)

This is my error
I am using fragments and I don't know whats wrong. Please answer. Thanks. :)

CODE FOR MY FRAGMENT

```
public class ByobovateFragment extends Fragment {

private static final String URL_DATA = "http://192.168.8.7/android_login_api/leafshape.php";

private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;

private List<ListItem> listItems;

private void loadRecycleViewData() {
    final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
    progressDialog.setMessage("Loading data...");
    progressDialog.show();

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL_DATA, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String s) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(s);
                JSONArray array = jsonObject.getJSONArray("tem");

                for(int i = 0; i<array.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject o = array.getJSONObject(i);
                    ListItem item = new ListItem(
                            o.getString("name"),
                            o.getString("scientificname"),
                            o.getString("image_url")
                    );
                    listItems.add(item);
                }

                adapter = new MyAdapter(listItems, getActivity().getApplicationContext());
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    },
            new Response.ErrorListener(){
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
public ByobovateFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.recyclerView_obovate);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));

    listItems = new ArrayList<>();

    loadRecycleViewData();
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_byobovate, container, false);
}
```

Comment: Post your fragment code. Looks like your recyclerView is not initialized.

Comment: where exactly is your recyclerview? in activity or in fragment?

Comment: It's in the fragment sir. Sorry I'm still a beginner. @AswinPAshok

Comment: post fragment layout. Are you following androidhive tutorial?

Comment: No. I just have the same package name sir.

Comment: <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
android:id="@+id/recyclerView_obovate"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"></android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

Comment: This is my recyclerview @AswinPAshok

Comment: So it is in fragment layout?

Comment: `View fragmentView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_byobovate, container, false);

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView_obovate);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));

    listItems = new ArrayList<>();

    loadRecycleViewData();
    return fragmentView;`

try this

Comment: it worked thanks :)

Comment: :) you are welcome...